# Two servers in domain but only one responsible for sending emails

Tags: postfix, email-server

I have two Debian servers:

```
web.example.com - LAMP web server
mail.example.com - mail server with postfix, dovecot and mysql based user directories, auth required
```

Now I want to setup web.example.com to send emails (ex. those that are sent by local services to root@web.example.com) using mail.example.com. I can say that I want mail.example.com to "trust" "web.example.com" in mail delivery.

How can I achieve this goal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To always permit realying on `mail.example.com` by `web.example.com`, you can add `web.example.com` to your trusted network:

```
mynetworks = 127.0.0.1/32 [your IPv4 and IPV6 addresses] [IP of web.example.com]
```

Alternatively you can use [`smtpd_client_restrictions`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_client_restrictions):

```
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/maps/client_access
```

with the following contents of `/etc/postfix/maps/client_access`:

```
[IP of web.example.com]     OK
```